# DTN routing protocol in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, dtn

I want simulate two DTN protocols (Prophet and Spray-ans-Wait protocols) using OMNET++ simulator.
Is there a framework in OMNET++ that leads to do that please? If no, which framework can I modify to simulate DTN protocols?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you finish your work?